# How to find the minimum time required to solve all N problems?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was trying to solve this problem but even after hours I am not able
to understand the problem completely. I am not even able to come up
with any brute force techniques.This is the question:

> There are N members and N problems and each member must exactly solve
>   1 problem.Only one member of the from the team is allowed to read the
>   problem statements before anyone start to solve.
>
> Note that not everyone have read the problems at first. So, to solve
>   problems a member needs to know the statements from some teammate who
>   already knows them. After knowing problems once, a member is eligible
>   to explain them to other teammates ( one teammate at a time ). You can
>   assume that the explaining ( 1 or N problems ) will always take D
>   minutes. During explaining, none of the two involved members will be
>   able to do anything else.
>
> Problems are of different difficulty levels. You can assume that it
>   will take Ti minutes to solve the ith problem, regardless of which
>   member solves it.
>
> Given a team's data, what is the minimum possible time in which they
>   can solve all problems?

Input

```
N  D
2 100

T=[1 2]

Output

102
```

> Member 1 is allowed to know problems before start time. He starts
>   explaing problems to member 2 when contest starts. Explaining ends at
>   the 100th minute. Then both of them immidiately starts solving
>   problems parallely. Member 1 solved 1st problem at the 101th minute
>   and member 2 solved 2nd problem at the 102th minute.

What is the best method to decode this type of problem and to approach it?

Comment: How large can `N` be? Can we pick who gets to know all problems before the starting time, or is it always Member 1?

Comment: @IVlad N≤3×10^3 . and yes we can choose any member..not necessarily 1..

Comment: The problem statement doesn't make a lot of sense. Given the conditions that you state, it will always take `D + N` minutes to solve all of the problems. Now, if a member can start working on a problem immediately after it is explained to him (i.e. he doesn't have to wait for all of the problems to be explained), then you have something to solve.

Comment: @JimMischel But 1 member can only solve one question and once he solved the question he has to sit Idle . So we need to make sure we end up solving all question in minimum time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This reminds me of [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).

I am not sure if the following approach is optimal, but it will probably give a good answer in practice.

1. Pick the easiest two problems T0 and T1 and replace them by a single problem consisting of time D+max(T0,T1).
2. Repeat until you have a single problem left

Finding the two easiest problems can be done in O(logN) if you store the problems in a binary heap, so overall this is O(NlogN).

### Example

Suppose we have 1,3,4,6 and D=2.

We first combine 1 and 3 to make 2+max(1,3)=5.  The new list is 4,5,6

We then combine 4 and 5 to make 2+max(4,5)=7. The new list is 6,7.

We then combine 6 and 7 to make 2+max(6,7)=9.

This represents the following procedure.

```
t=0 A shares with B
t=2 A starts problem 6, B shares with C
t=4 B starts problem 4, C shares with D
t=6 C starts problem 3, D starts problem 1
t=7 D finishes
t=8 A finishes, B finishes
t=9 C finishes
```

Comment: I actually haven't been able to find a counterexample so far, do you have one? It would be great if it turned out that this is optimal.

Comment: I don't have a counter example, I'm just not feeling brave enough to attempt a proof...

Comment: so do we need to sort time and solve with greedy strategy i.e solve the highest execution time first then second highest, etc??

Comment: Not quite, it is more a greedy strategy that solves the two shortest tasks last (where a task is either one of the original problems, or a combination of problems that have already been combined)

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz  Why can't we sort the time T to get the two easiest problem. It take O(n^2lohn) time as we will have to sort after each merge of two easiest problem.

Comment: @Ashish you certainly can do this if you wish, but O(n^2logn) is slower than the O(nlogn) method if you use a heap

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz  btw how did you relate this question with hamming coding.

Comment: @גלעדברקן  this in fact will give optimal solution.Solved with greedy strategy ..

Comment: @Ashish can you help me see one example of an input where the solution cannot have the tasks ordered from longest to shortest (meaning that the task with the largest T will start first, followed by the next longest T, etc.)?

Comment: @גלעדברקן  There is no need for them to be in any order because we will sort the array anyway. Moreover we need to find minimum time so removing larger element form array first will always be helpful.

Comment: @Ashish : sorry for the confusion - I meant Huffman not Hamming

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz I kept on trying to relate between them... :)

Comment: @Ashish (and Peter) I'm talking about the solution - in the solution, tasks and explanations are ordered in a certain way for least overall time (Peter has an example at the end of his answer: "t=0 A shares with B...etc.") My current understanding is that *all* solutions must have the tasks in descending order of difficulty (which might validate an alternate answer method). Can you help me see one example of an input where the solution cannot have the tasks ordered from longest to shortest (meaning that the task with the largest T will start first, followed by the next longest T, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

Every member of the team (except the one who read the problems)
must hear the problems. That is, problems must be told `N - 1` times.
For `N = 2` this can be done in `D` minutes, 
for `2 < N <= 4` in `2D` minutes,
for `4 < N <= 8` in `3D` minutes, etc.

If `N` is not an exact power of 2 then some people must finish telling
the problems at least `D` minutes sooner than others. 
The ones who finish early can work on
the hardest problems, leaving easier problems for the ones who finish later.

If some of the problems take time `Ti > D` and `N` is neither an exact
power of 2 nor one less than an exact power of 2, you may want to have
someone stop telling problems *more* than `D` minutes before
the last problem-telling is finished.

If some of the problems take time `Ti > 2D` then you may need to consider
making some people stop telling problems and start working on the really
hard problems sooner even if `N` is an exact power of 2.

Since the solving of one problem is in every member's critical path,
but telling is in multiple members' critical paths,
it makes no sense for anyone to solve a problem until they are finished
with all the telling of problems they are going to do.
After each `D` minutes the number of people who know the problems
increases by the number who were telling problems.
The number who are telling problems increases by the number who
were telling problems (that is, the number who have just learned the
problems) minus the number who start working on problems at that time.

A good "brute force" approach might be to sort the problems
by difficulty; then find out the time until the last person hears
the problems if nobody starts working on them before then;
find out when the last person finishes; 
then try starting problems `D` minutes earlier, or `2D` minutes,
or `3D` minutes, etc., but never start a shorter-running
problem before a longer-running one.

Comment: "Every member of the team... must hear the problems" --- no. It may be faster for the first member to actually solve them all instead of describing.

Comment: @Petr - no, the problem statement says that each member must solve a single problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry, did not notice this

Comment: The solution by Peter de Rivaz looks like a good heuristic for most cases and I have tried unsuccessfully to find a counterexample. My guess is that will turn out to be the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement is somewhat ambiguous about the explaining part. Depending on how the statement is interpreted, the following solution is possible:

If you assume that you can explain N problems in D minutes, then it takes `N/D` minutes to explain one problem. Let's call that `Te`, for "time to explain". And the time to solve Problem `i` is `Ti`, which we know is equal to `i` minutes.

So at the start of the contest, Member 1 (who knows all of the problems) explains problem N to Member 2. That takes `Te` minutes. Member 2 then begins working on problem N (which will take N minutes to solve), and Member 1 starts explaining problem N-1 to Member 3. This continues until Member 1 explains problem 2 to Member N. At that point, Member N starts working on problem 2, and Member 1 starts working on problem 1.

Let's say that there are 4 problems, 4 team members, and `D=8`. So `Te=2`.

```
Time    Description
 0      Member 1 begins explaining Problem 4 to Member 2
 2      Member 2 begins working on Problem 4
        Member 1 begins explaining Problem 3 to Member 3
 4      Member 3 begins working on Problem 3
        Member 1 begins explaining Problem 2 to Member 4
 6      Member 2 completes problem 4
        Member 4 begins working on Problem 2
        Member 1 begins working on Problem 1
 7      Member 3 completes Problem 3
        Member 1 completes Problem 1
 8      Member 4 completes Problem 2
```

This seems like the optimum solution regardless of the value of `D` or `N`: arrange it so that the problem that takes the longest to solve is started as early as possible.

I suspect that the problem statement is an English translation of a problem given in some other language or perhaps a re-translation of something that was originally written in English and translated into some other language. Because if that's the original problem statement, whoever wrote it should be barred from ever writing problems again.

Answer (score 0):

The length of time it takes to complete any one task seems of the form `C * D + T, where C is a positive integer less than N`, and all `N-1` lead-times must be accounted for. Suppose we made a mistake and the optimal solution should actually have a task coupled with a longer lead time - so some `C * D + Tj < C * D + Ti, where Ti < Tj`, which is impossible.

Therefore, iterate once over the sums of pairs (assuming sorted input):

```
solution = maximum (T2 + (n-1) * D, T3 + (n-2) * D...D + Tn)
```